# How to send debug prints from Windows driver to somewhere else than WinDbg?

Tags: windows, driver, windbg

I'm writing a custom kernel-driver for Windows 8.1, and use `DbgPrintEx` to print my debug messages, which are sent to a WinDbg on my host machine. WinDbg makes me too much problems, and I just want to be able to send my prints to some local log file (on the target machine) instead, is it possible to do so in some not-very-complicated way?

Comment: Can you add this answer below? DebugView from sysinternal worked for me really well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

converted comment to answer
use `DebugView /xxx` on the target either from `sysinternals` or `osronline`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [WPP Software Tracing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff545581(v=vs.85).aspx), and then use [TraceView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff553872(v=vs.85).aspx) to view it on the target machine. TraceView gives you the option to save the trace session to a log file.